# GWT Super Dev Mode is not finding css

Tags: debugging, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm trying to use Super Dev Mode, but after clicking on the `Compile` button all the styling disappears from my app and the code server outputs messages like:

```
[WARN] not found: /tmp/gwt-codeserver-3963094913939458195.tmp/co.company.MainDev/compile-2/war/co.company.Main/cms/skin.css.gz
```

I'm using GWT 2.5.0 and no special arguments with the Code Server.

How can I remedy this?